# H2 Schema Empty in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2

I'm setting up a barebones Spring Boot project [described here](https://github.com/gregturn/draft-tut-react-and-spring-data-rest/tree/master/basic) and I'm running into issues with the basic setup.

It seems that the DatabaseLoader does not get invoked, and when I open the H2 Console for this project I see no schema containing an Employee table.

Here's the relevant part of my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <!-- 
        <scope>runtime</scope>
         -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

my domain:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String description;

    public Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String description) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

And the database loader:
    public class DatabaseLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
        private final EmployeeRepository repository;

```
    @Autowired
    public DatabaseLoader(EmployeeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        this.repository.save(new Employee("duke", "earl", "dude"));
    }

}
```

Navigating to the console after application startup at localhost:8080/console shows jdbc:h2:~/test with only an INFORMATION_SCHEMA and users menu. I also set this up as a CRUD repository and, though I can post to it, none of the attribute data seems to be saved, but the Employees resource is recognized.

```
POST:{"firstName": "Bilbo", "lastName": "Baggxins", "description": "burglar"}
```

Comes back with:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/employees/4"
    },
    "employee": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/employees/4"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The default h2 url with Spring Boot is: `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb`**

To use `jdbc:h2:~/test` you must add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
```

What's happening is, you are writing the Employee in spring-boot's memory database (testdb). Then, you open the h2-console to `jdbc:h2:~/test`, which creates it on the fly, and let you browse emptiness.

With `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` you may open a browser to `http://localhost:8080/h2-console` and view the database content. Use the following settings:

- Saved Settings: Generic H2 (Embedded)
- Driver Class: org.h2.Driver
- URL: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
- username: sa
- password:

Comment: that did get the console working- thanks! Submitting my post creates a record in the table but the name and description fields are all null. It may be a Lombok issue which is also new to me and I am investigating this now

Comment: I'll try it now, but I'm pretty much copy-pasting from the tutorial "React.js and Spring Data REST: Part 1" so I'm not sure why it wouldn't just work as advertised

Comment: I added getter/setters manually and it worked. Weird! I'll investigate why that is, but thanks for your help

Comment: btw, is there a way to open up the console to point to jdbc:h2:mem:testdb?

Comment: I did not add Lombok to my project as I wasn't aware that was necessary. Man, I'm way out of my league here! But that did work. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121497/discussion-between-iceddante-and-alex).

Answer (score 0):

This is shamelessly borrowed from Josh Long.  This is a working `CommandLineRunner` implementation.  [Github full code](https://github.com/joshlong/bootiful-microservices/blob/master/bootiful-microservices-brixton/reservation-service/src/main/java/com/example/ReservationServiceApplication.java)

```
@Component
class SampleRecordsCLR implements CommandLineRunner {

  private final ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

  @Autowired
  public SampleRecordsCLR(ReservationRepository reservationRepository) {
    this.reservationRepository = reservationRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      Stream.of("Josh", "Jungryeol", "Nosung", "Hyobeom",
              "Soeun", "Seunghue", "Peter", "Jooyong")
              .forEach(name -> reservationRepository.save(new Reservation(name)));

      reservationRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```